# Flex 4 - How to loop over children of a container when they are state-dependant

Tags: apache-flex, element, children, states

Flex's new States re-parents visual items that are marked with includeIn/excludeFrom. If I have a Group (MainGroup) with 5 children/elements that are state controlled, is there still a way to get a reference to MainGroup's children? mainGroup.numChildren and mainGroup.numElements don't work since the children are re-parented. At best, they show 1.

```
<s:states>
   <s:State name="view1State" />
   <s:State name="view2State" />
   <s:State name="view3State" />
   <s:State name="view4State" />
</s:states>

<s:Group id="mainGroup">
    <shipping:OrderShipping id="view1"
            includeIn="view1State" />
    <payment:OrderPayment id="view2"
            includeIn="view2State" />
    <verification:OrderVerification id="view3"
            includeIn="view3State" />
    <confirmation:OrderConfirmation id="view4"
            includeIn="view4State" />
</s:Group>
```

Comment: Note: the "re-parenting" is really just having the parent nullified. Here are the changed properties on a visual item that has been removed by a state-change:
Here is the changed properties on a visual item that has been removed by a state-change:

- automationOwner: null, 
- automationParent: null, 
- baselinePosition: NaN, 
- document: null, 
- filters: null, 
- focusManager: null, 
- listeners: empty, 
- loaderInfo: null, 
- nestLevel: 0, 
- owner: null, 
- parent: null, 
- parentChangedFlag: true, 
-parentDocument: null, 
-systemManagerDirty: true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the best answer! Well, I will let you decide. Just operate on the states array...

```
 for each (var viewState:State in mainDocument.states)
{
    var overrides:Array = viewState.overrides;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < overrides.length; i++)
    {
        var addItems:AddItems = overrides[i];
        if (addItems.destination === mainDocument.mainGroup)
            trace((addItems.items as UIComponent).name);
    }

}
```

Comment: @NoobsArePeople2, this is really the same idea as your solution. Just nice to know where Adobe put it and might save some lines of code. Note: It will only contain items that have been created. So deferred instatiation still applies.

Answer (score 2):

If you want states to control visible/includeinlayout rather than parenthood, just do it like this

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="view1State" />
    <s:State name="view2State" />
    <s:State name="view3State" />
    <s:State name="view4State" />
</s:states>
<s:Group id="mainGroup">
    <shipping:OrderShipping id="view1" 
        visible="false" 
        includeInLayout="false" 
        visible.view1State="true" 
        includeInLayout.view1State="true"/>
    <payment:OrderPayment id="view2" 
        visible="false" 
        includeInLayout="false" 
        visible.view2State="true" 
        includeInLayout.view2State="true"/>
    <verification:OrderVerification id="view3" 
        visible="false" 
        includeInLayout="false" 
        visible.view3State="true" 
        includeInLayout.view3State="true" />
    <confirmation:OrderConfirmation id="view4" 
        visible="false" 
        includeInLayout="false"
        visible.view4State="true" 
        includeInLayout.view4State="true"/>
</s:Group>
```

Comment: Ah, an interesting mix of old-skool and new-skool. Still somewhat of a hack IMO but certainly is a viable solution. The one drawback is that you would no longer be getting the benefit of deferred instatiation.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar situation in one of my applications and this is how I accomplished things.  I feel obliged to say that, though this works I feel it is a bit hacky.  With that in mind:

1. Create another state, we'll call it `cheating`.  Make this state the default one (put it first in your `states` array.
2. Update all your views to be included in this state.
   E.g.,  `<shipping:OrderShipping id="view1" includeIn="cheating,view1State" />`
3. Create a new class member of type `Array` called `views`.
4. Add a `creationComplete` event handler.  In the handler populdate `views` with references to each of the views.  E.g., `views = [view1, view2, view3, view4];`
5. Change the state to your "first" (non-`cheating`) state: `setCurrentState("view1State");`

After all this your `views` array will have references to each of the views regardless of which state your application is currently in.

Comment: That is an interesting solution indeed. The only problem I can see is that the array might be holding reference to something that would otherwise be GCed. I like the idea though. I think I would use a Dictionary with weakKeys=true instead of the Array though. For now, I dumped the loop and hard-coded it :-(

`if (view1)
  (view1 as IViewResetable).resetView();
 if (view2)
  (view2 as IViewResetable).resetView();
 if (view3)
  (view3 as IViewResetable).resetView();
 if (view4)
  (view4 as IViewResetable).resetView();
 if (view5)
  (view5 as IViewResetable).resetView();`

Comment: Yeah, `Dictionary` would probably be a better choice wrt GC.  In my specific case I don't need to worry about it because my views are created when the app starts and only destroyed when it quits.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the underlying state implementation removes / adds children to the component or changes their visibility.

If the former, I'd try something like this:

```
for (var x : int = 0; x<mainGroup.numChildren ; x++){
 var child : UIComponent = mainGroup.getChildAt(x);
 if(child.parent){
   // The child has a parent, so it must be displayed; do your processing 
 } else {
   // really this should never occur 
 }
}
```

If it is a visibility issue, then do this:

```
for (var x : int = 0; x<mainGroup.numChildren ; x++){
 var child : UIComponent = mainGroup.getChildAt(x);
 if(child.visible){
   // The child is displayed; do your processing 
 } else {
   // child isn't displayed
 }
}
```

I'd guess the first approach is the correct one.

[Note I wrote this code in the browser]

Comment: The problem is that numChildren was always 0 or 1 because only one component is displaying. The others are re-parented, no longer in mainGroup, by Flex until their includeIn state matches the currentState. It is really odd to me that includeIn/excludeFrom doesn't just set visibility and includeInLayout.

Comment: @Tony Smith I thought that was what you wanted; to get the component's children.  It sounds to me now like you want to get all possible children; not all current children?  That was not clear to me at all from the original question.  Is that the case?

Comment: Oh sorry man, I'll try to be more clear next time. So in my example, I am trying to loop over all of mainGroup's children, views 1-4. I found a pretty cool solution though as posted below.